# Prove that ${x dy - y d x\over x^2 + y^2}$ is not exact

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms

Please can someone verify my proof that
$$\psi = {x dy - y d x\over x^2 + y^2}$$
is not exact?

Here is my work:

If $\psi$ was exact there would exist $f:\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ such that $df = f_x dx + f_y dy = \psi$. Here $f_x = {-y \over x^2 + y^2}$ and $f_y = {x \over x^2 + y^2}$.

It would hold true that
$$\int f_x dx = \int f_y dy = f.$$
So I calculate these integrals:

$$ \int f_x dx = -{1\over 2}\log(x^2 + y^2)$$

and

$$ \int f_y dy = {1\over 2}\log(x^2 + y^2)$$

It is clear that these cannot be equal therefore $\psi$ is not exact.

**Edit**

The first thing I had tried (it did not work) was to calculate the integral along a closed curve:

$$ \int_{S^1}\psi = \int_{S^1} {x \over x^2 + y^2} dy - \int_{S^1} {y \over x^2 + y^2} dx = \int_{S^1} x dy - \int_{S^1} y dx= x \int_{S^1}  dy - y \int_{S^1}  dx = 0$$

since $\int_{S^1}dx = 0$.

Comment: If $\psi$ was exact on $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\} $, then the integral of $\psi $ along any closed loop in $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\} $ is zero. Can you find a loop $ c $ in $\Bbb R^2-\{0\} $ such that $\int_c \psi $ is nonzero?

Comment: @kobe Are you saying my solution is wrong?

Comment: In your solution, $\int f_x\, dx = \int f_y\, dy = f$, but in fact $\int f_x\, dx = f(x,y) + g(y)$ and $\int f_y\, dy = f(x,y) + h(x)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$. The two integrals need not be the same.

Comment: Indeed.  The thing to do here is apply the fact that a $1$-form $\omega$ is exact $\iff$ $\int_C \omega = 0$ for all closed curves $C$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand my mistake. Could someone please say a bit more?

Comment: @kobe Why is the partial integral of $f_x$ with respect to $x$ $f(x,y) + g(y)$? Where does the function $g(y)$ come from?

Comment: Your $f$ is a function of variables $x$ and $y$, so $\int f_x\, dx$ differs from $f$ by a constant independent of $x$. This constant independent of $x$ must then be a function of $y$. So $\int f_x\, dx = f(x,y) + g(y)$ for some function $g(y)$.

Comment: @kobe Why "must be" a function of $y$? Did you mean "can be"?

Comment: @kobe Regarding your other comment: before I solved it like this I computed the integral along $S^1$ and it turned out to be zero.

Comment: $$ \int_{S^1}\psi = \int_{S^1} {x \over x^2 + y^2} dy - \int_{S^1} {y \over x^2 + y^2} dx = \int_{S^1} x dy - \int_{S^1} y dx = 0$$

Comment: The partial integral $\int f_x\, dx$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, so $g := \int f_x\, dx - f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ that is independent of $x$. Hence $g$ varies with $y$ alone.

Comment: In $\int_{S^1} x \, \mathrm{d}y$, $x$ is not a constant, so you can't factor it out.

Comment: First things first. You need to learn the definition of a line integral. $\displaystyle\int_C x\,dy = \int_a^b x(t)\dfrac{dy}{dt}dt$ when the curve is parametrized by $\big(x(t),y(t)\big)$, $a\le t\le b$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, your comment helped. But isn't your formula missing an absolute value? I looked it up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field) and there the expression in the integral is $f(r) \cdot |r'|$.

Comment: No, what you're talking about is a line integral of the form $\displaystyle\int_C f\,ds$.

Comment: @TedShifrin How did you go from $\int_C f ds$ to $\int_C x dy$? First, replace $f= f(x,y)=x$ in the integral and then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Green's theorem,

$$\int_{S^1} \psi = \int_{S^1} x\, dy - y\, dx = \iint_{D^2} \text{div}(\langle x,y\rangle)\, dA = 2\cdot \text{Area}(D^2) = 2\pi$$

Alternatively, parametrize $S^1$ by setting $x = \cos(t)$, $y = \sin(t)$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$. Then $$\int_{S^1} \psi = \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos(t)\cdot \cos(t) - \sin(t)\cdot (-\sin(t)))\, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t))\, dt = 2\pi$$

Either way, $\int_{S^1} \psi \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you. But where is the mistake in $$ \int_{S^1}\psi = \int_{S^1} {x \over x^2 + y^2} dy - \int_{S^1} {y \over x^2 + y^2} dx = \int_{S^1} x dy - \int_{S^1} y dx = 0$$ I don't understand.

Comment: You're correct up to the last step: $\int_{S^1} x\, dy \neq \int_{S^1} y\, dx$.

Comment: The integral $\int_{S^1} x\, dy $ is positive, but $\int_{S^1} y\, dx$ is negative.

Comment: I don't understand: $\int x dy = x \int dy$. And since $\int_{S^1} dx = 0$, $x \int dy = 0$ and $y \int dx = 0$. What is the mistake?

Comment: You're misinterpreting the meanings of $\int_{S^1} x\, dy$ and $\int_{S^1} y\, dx$. These integrals are line integrals in the plane. The equation $\int_{S^1} x\, dy = x\int_{S^1} dy$ does not make sense because $\int_{S^1} x\, dy$ is constant and $x\int_{S^1} dy$ is variable.